# Проверка установлено ли приложение и его удаление

Tags: android

Собственно, как реализовать проверку на то установлено ли на телефон опредленное приложение (нужно две проверки, проверка по package и имени).  И как возможно программно удалять приложения из телефона? И еше, возможно ли получать событие, когда новое приложение установлено, и проверять его package и имя?

Comment: А нельзя удалить как удаляем обычный файл? Просто удалить папку с приложением?


Comment: Нет, в андройде всё по другому

Comment: Теоретически конечно можно, правда есть 2 ограничения:/

1) Нужно иметь рут права

2) Сломается менеджер приложений, не так вроде страшно, он сам себе и вылечится, просто могут быть нестандартные ситуации

Answer (score 9, accepted):

После установки какого-либо приложения приходит широковещательный Intent `PACKAGE_ADDED`. Надо его получить и обработать.

Манифест.

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Обработчик.

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Обработать
    }
```

}

А наличие установленного приложения можно проверить с помощью PackageManager.

```
// packageName - имя пакета
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);

if (pi != null) {
    // TODO: Обработать
}
```

Автоматически программно удалять приложения с обычного телефона нельзя - нужно подтверждение пользователя.